# How to create equalizer effect in ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to create an equalizer effect in ios app for the button which appears only when the button is clicked. Equalizer effect is similar to [image]

How to achieve this??.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Superpowered](http://superpowered.com) sound library.  I've used it for sound manipulation and visualization in one of my latest project.  In particular, the [Music Analysis (bpm detection, key detection, waveforms, filter bank)](http://superpowered.com/music-analysis-bpm-key-detection-waveform#waveform) will probably where you will want to dig.

They also have a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/superpoweredSDK/Low-Latency-Android-Audio-iOS-Audio-Engine) with sample projects.